# Change java-mode's indentation style in emacs

Tags: java, emacs, indentation

My emacs is configured with c-default-style as "linux" and c-basic-offset as 4, which I am really happy with and works like a charm with C and PHP. The thing is that when I try to edit some java code it is indented like this:

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
        {
            System.out.println("Hello world!");
        }
}
```

Which is apparently Emacs's default behaviour for indenting and not the one I set for CC-mode (what bothers me is the indentation of the braces for the main function). I only started using Emacs a few months ago and I'm not that comfortable with Emacs Lisp, but really have no idea why java-mode isn't picking up cc-mode's indent style. Does someone have any clues with this ? Of course, disabling indent-tabs-mode is a solution but I have to say I don't find it satisfactory. I have a feeling this problem really has a simple solution, but I've been looking for hours...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what works for me:

```
(require 'google-c-style)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
      (lambda()
            (subword-mode)
            (google-set-c-style)
            (google-make-newline-indent)
            (setq c-basic-offset 4)))
```

You'll need to download
https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/google-c-style.el
and put it somewhere in your load path, for instance in `~/.emacs.d/`.

Comment: Thanks, but the lambda definition must be defined in the form `#'(lambda () ...)` in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the "c style" (rules for indenting C-like languages) is described briefly [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Custom-C-Indent.html).  In particular, you can use something like this to select "linux" for java-mode:

```lisp
(setq c-default-style
      '((java-mode . "linux")))
```

I believe you need to select the style for each mode separately.  java-mode probably isn't picking up on c-default-style as a string for some reason.

Comment: That did nothing...But I do think a solution that does not resort to external configuration files -- there has to be a simple way to do it. But as you say, I don't understand why java-mode isn't picking up on c-default style.